# How to change the precision of BigDecimal in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using **BigDecimal** in domains as type. If I check the generated schema in the database (mySql), the column type is **decimal(19,2)**.
I can change it by using constraints in the Domain class ( [as decribed in Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Constraints/scale.html)) like:

```
static constraints = {
     salary (scale: 3, maxSize:32)
}
```

My question is: how to define the scale and maxSize for all fields of type BigDecimal in my application?

I have already tried to define it in the config.groovy like that

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(scale:10, size:32, class:BigDecimal)
}
```

or like that:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    '*'(scale:10, size:32, class:BigDecimal)
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Grails vesion is 2.2.2.

Answer (score 7):

The scale constraint allows you to control this:

```
...
BigDecimal myNum

static constraints = {
   myNum(scale: 6)
}
...
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/scale.html

Comment: The challenge is to define for ALL properties of type BigDecimal. (ALL = in the whole application)

Answer (score 6):

The best way i found to do this is the following:

In your Config.groovy you define the following:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
  myCustomScale( scale: 10, max: 9999999999999999999999.99999999 )
}
```

In your Domain Object you add the following contraint:

```
static constraints = {      
  myField shared: 'myCustomScale'
}
```

You can use this contraint for all your BigDecimal fields where needed.
If you need to adjust the scale (lets say for a specific customer) you can control this by changing it in the config.

Hope this helps